# MySQL get latest result with specifc ID?

Tags: mysql

I have following mySQL table

```
id   userid        document            created_date
___________________________________________________________
1  |     39 | 3985_doc_1363249277 | 2013-03-15 10:03:14
2  |     39 | 3985_doc_1363319837 | 2013-03-06 11:57:17
3  |     39 | 3985_doc_1363321078 | 2013-02-05 12:17:58
4  |     24 | 1524_doc_1363328910 | 2013-03-15 14:28:30
5  |     24 | 1524_doc_1363586975 | 2013-03-18 14:09:35
```

I want to select the latest document which userid is '39'. 
The document with created_date '2013-03-15 10:03:14' will be the result.

How do I query the database to achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTableName
WHERE userid = 39
ORDER BY created_day DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

select * from table_name where userid=39 order by created_date desc limit 0,1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE userid = 39
ORDER BY created_day  DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Here LIMIT 1 is to specify no of records

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *                     // <<== select only the columns you want
FROM    tableName
WHERE   userid = 39
ORDER   BY created_date DESC
LIMIT   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT document FROM TABLE WHERE userid = 39 ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserID, Max(Created_Date) from table Where UserID = 39 group by UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL, using LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE userid=3985 
ORDER BY created_date desc 
LIMIT 0,1
```